# Rails 4 change controller scope with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, scope

I have a User model wich has a controller index and an '.all' scope
ex: `User.all`

Is there a decent way to switch to a different scope when you clic on a view link?
I want to display all user when a user clic an 'all' link or a scoped version when he clic on an other link.

Do i have to use a gem like has_scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped) method, for example:

```
@users = User.scoped
@users = @users.your_scope if params[:your_scope_param]
```

all you have to do is to bind appropriate param to your "scoping" link, it should be like:

```
<%= link_to 'Scoped users', users_path(your_scope_param: true) %>
```

Comment: Ok great i think it's working but i dont get how to make the view link for sending the scope param.